# Как убрать автофокус с кнопки?

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я навожу курсор на `Old password` и нажимаю Enter, у меня автоматически нажимается кнопка `Change Password`. Как сделать так, чтобы она не срабатывала? (Это надо сделать не через html, а через ООП)

Comment: Не издеваться над пользователем и не делать так.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мне наоборот кажется, что его это может триггерить, потому что со мной такое часто бывает

Comment: С чего ты взял, что он поля будет подряд заполнять?

Comment: Отправка формы по нажатию Enter — это стандартное поведение абсолютно везде, и кнопка здесь вообще ни при чём (форма всё равно будет отправляться, даже если убрать эту кнопку). Не нужно ломать привычки пользователям.

Comment: Поставь валидатор на JS который будет прынгать на незаполненное поле